# Add layers dependent on `OVERRIDES`

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have encapsulated some functionality and modifications in a single layer. What would be my first go-to solution to have a flexible integration would be to add the concerning layer in my `bblayers.conf` based on an `OVERRIDE` named nied such as:

```
BBLAYERS_append_nied = " meta-nied"
```

Unfortunately, the parsing order does not allow that, right? What would be the standard way to add the encapsulated functionality in my multiconfig setup? Having an `_nied` appended to each appending recipe does not seem correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, layers shouldn't impact much the build system. Especially their order of inclusion in `BBLAYERS`, better if not at all. If you want recipes that depend on machines, look into `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` or use appropriate machine overrides for variables (note you can't make a bbappend apply to `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` but not the original recipe), if some are specific to some distro features, look into `REQUIRED_DISTRO_FEATURES`, etc...

You can make an init script wrapping `oe-init-buildenv` that leverages `BBMASK` to mask some parts of layers.

Best way is to make your layer nice to others, in which case you most probably don't need to care about including it or not depending on the presence of something else.